# Android Studio crashes on startup. I will add the error code, how can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I think there is a problem with the plugins and I'm stuck here. Thinking that Android Studio might be corrupted, I reinstalled Studio. This was not a solution. By the way, I apologize for any translation errors.

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException: Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design, org.jetbrains.android
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:854)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1068)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr
```

Comment: What AntiVirus system is installed? If you reinstall Android Studio and get the same error some system may corrupt your installation. Anti Virus would be one possibility. Also consider deleting (or moving away) not only Android Studio itself but also the related data in your user folder like `.android` and the AndroidStudio folders in the user app data folder (roaming and local if I remember correctly).

Comment: have you tried using visual studio code? It offers everything android studio does without the performance issues of android studio.

Comment: Thanks for help I solved this problem. I found a txt file in the folder of the old version of Android Studio. The names of the plugins used were written inside. I embedded this .txt file into the new version.

Comment: Actually, it made sense to use Visual Studio Code, but here are some habits :) @CStark